# Error using Pandas Groupby and date_range for timeseries analysis

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a Pandas DataFrame similar to the one below, and I am trying to split the DataFrame into week long chunks, and run a function on each chunk.  I believe this should be able to be done with the `groupby` and `date_range` functions, but I'm having some trouble.

I've seen others do something similar using date as an index.  However, this will not work in this situation, as multiple lines in the df might have the same date.  Also, every date is not represented in the df.

What am I doing wrong with the `groupby` and/or the`date_range` functions?

Once I get this figured out, I want to use `nx.from_pandas_dataframe` to create a network for each week long chunk and calculate the number of nodes in each chunk.

```
# create list of edges with 'source', 'target', 'timestamp'
edges = [('e', 'a1', '12/02/2015'),
         ('e', 'a2', '12/02/2015'),
         ('e', 'a3', '12/03/2015'),
         ('e', 'a4', '12/04/2015'),
         ('e', 'a5', '12/04/2015'),
         ('e', 'a1', '12/08/2015'),
         ('e', 'a2', '12/09/2015'),
         ('e', 'a6', '12/09/2015'),
         ('e', 'a7', '12/13/2015'),
         ('e', 'a1', '12/15/2015'),
         ('e', 'a6', '12/16/2015'),
         ('e', 'a8', '12/17/2015'),
         ('e', 'a9', '12/18/2015')]

# create a DataFrame from edges
df = pd.DataFrame(edges, columns=['source', 'target', 'date'], )

# sort df by date and identify first and last date
df.sort(columns=['date'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
first_date = df.date.irow(0)
last_date = df.date.irow(-1)

df.groupby(pd.date_range(start=first_date, end=last_date, freq='W'))
AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ones, but here is one solution.  I create a dictionary of dataframes keyed off of the year/week tuple pair.

First, I create a column in the dataframe of year/week tuple pairs. Then I use a dictionary comprehension to group on this column.

```
df['year_week'] = [(d.year, d.week) for d in df['date']]

weekly_groups = {w: g for w, g in df.groupby('year_week')}
>>> weekly_groups
{(2015, 49):   source target       date   year_week
 0      e     a1 2015-12-02  (2015, 49)
 1      e     a2 2015-12-02  (2015, 49)
 2      e     a3 2015-12-03  (2015, 49)
 3      e     a4 2015-12-04  (2015, 49)
 4      e     a5 2015-12-04  (2015, 49),
 (2015, 50):   source target       date   year_week
 5      e     a1 2015-12-08  (2015, 50)
 6      e     a2 2015-12-09  (2015, 50)
 7      e     a6 2015-12-09  (2015, 50)
 8      e     a7 2015-12-13  (2015, 50),
 (2015, 51):    source target       date   year_week
 9       e     a1 2015-12-15  (2015, 51)
 10      e     a6 2015-12-16  (2015, 51)
 11      e     a8 2015-12-17  (2015, 51)
 12      e     a9 2015-12-18  (2015, 51)}
```